# How to write and persist data in a VOLUME of an image FROM which my Dockerfile is based?

Tags: docker, couchbase, dockerfile

Not sure my title is clear, sorry about that.

I have a `Dockerfile` which starts from a Couchbase image:

```
FROM couchbase:4.5.0
```

What I want to achieve in my `Dockerfile` is to start the Couchbase server, init some stuff (a cluster, a bucket, some design documents and some views).

Today I achieve it using:

```
COPY configure-cluster.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /configure-cluster.sh
RUN /configure-cluster.sh
```

And the content of `configure-cluster.sh`:

```
/entrypoint.sh couchbase-server &
sleep 15
couchbase-cli cluster-init \
-c localhost:8091 \
--cluster-init-username=Administrator \
--cluster-init-password=password \
--cluster-init-port=8091 \
--services=data,index,query,fts \
--cluster-ramsize=512 \
--cluster-index-ramsize=512 \
--cluster-fts-ramsize=256
# Additional bucket/design document/view configuration
```

However when I run the built image, I notice that none of my configuration is there. I am pretty sure this happens because in the `couchbase:4.5.0` [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/~/dockerfile/), the last step is

```
VOLUME /opt/couchbase/var
```

which is precisely the path where all the Couchbase configuration (cluster, bucket, design document, view) is stored. And according to [Docker's documentation on Dockerfile's VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume):

> Note: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it
>   has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

So my question is:
**Is there a clean way to achieve my need?** I feel like this is exactly the kind of things that should belong in a Dockerfile RUN step, and not in the ENTRYPOINT step (which is run at each start of a container, and not just during initialization of a container).

**Bonus question:** I don't see the point of declaring this VOLUME in Couchbase Dockerfile. They prevent users from preparing an image already customized for their needs, and I don't see why I would need to inject their empty volume in my container. Anyone has insight on this please?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this help... https://github.com/tophatch/CouchbaseMobileWithKubernetes/tree/master/docker/couchbase

Comment: @combinatorial Not really :( This is not included in the Docker image, but merely runs it at start if no other argument is passed during the RUN command. Moreover by default this runs every time. That's part of the "unclean" methods similar to the ENTRYPOINT one I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the configuration is stored inside the volume, and your child image is simply performing configurations that write to this volume, then a better solution is to use the parent image as-is, and initialize a volume when deploying your image.

Once the volume gets created in the parent image, there's no clean way to make a child image with different contents in this volume, about the best you can do is update the entrypoint to include an initialization step that copies some contents into the volume on startup when a flag file is missing, and include that flag file in your copy.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the volume but more with the way docker manages the ENTRYPOINT and CMD command.

What happens is that when you build your image, the RUN command does start a couchbase server with your right configuration data but when you actually start a container from your image, as you have not declared any entrypoint or CMD in your dockerfile, the CMD from the upper image will be launched.

I do not know anything about couchbase and the way the configuration works but my guess is the problem is there.

Now on the all VOLUME thing the point is making sure the data can be accessed from another container using the `--volumes-from` option of the docker run command line.

Once again, my knowledge about couchbase is null so I do not know how the configuration works but assuming the only thing you want to achieve is start the couchbase image with your own configuration files in `/opt/couchbase/var`, you do not need to build an image for that, just do a

```
docker run -d -v <path to your config>:/opt/couchbase/var couchbase:4.5.0
```

If you want to make it an image for better deployment, my recommandation would be to use a COPY command in your docker file for your conf file :

COPY ./myconf /opt/couchbase/var

without forgetting to use a right command or entrypoint at the end of your dockerfile [see comments on my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210548/does-docker-cmd-carry-on-from-upper-images-to-be-passed-as-argument-to-entrypoin)

Comment: I am not sure about your answer. I tried adding 
`ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["couchbase-server"]`
at the end of my Dockerfile and the problem remains. No trace of my data folders in the started container.

As for storing data folders in my versioned code and copy it at runtime, I disagree. What matters is how to configure it (i.e. the couchbase-cli commands in the `configure-cluster.sh` script). I will not store the full folder structure in my code. I want to write how to obtain the result, not the result directly (which is the whole point of Dockerfile).

Comment: @Bmitch phrases it better than I. Either configuration are all file stored and you can link them when you deploy your image using a -v option in the docker run command. Or you want to perform some actions at start and you need to write your own entrypoint file.